# $string is not showing in common.php

Tags: php, echo

Let's say I've got 2 files. 1 is common which loads all the design and stuff and one is index.

What I want to do is set a $ in index like this:

```
<?
$SubId3 = 'test';
include "../../common.php";
?>
```

Then in common I want to have something like

```
<?=$SubId3; if (empty($SubId3)) { echo 'homepage'; } ?>
```

I cannot seem to get this working. Meaning if I set it up this way. The index will never show "test".

What am i doing wrong here?
I want to do this since only certain files will contain the string $SubId3, to test some things on certain pages and not others (by adding `$SubId3 = 'test';` to that particular file)

Comment: Do only one thing in a `<?= ?>` tag: define the variable. I am guessing the `if` is just ignored or something like that. Use `<?php` for logic, `<?=` for simple output.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `<?=` is short-hand to **output** something (think of `<?=` as `<?php echo`) and not to execute any other sort of logic or code.

However, it is possible to use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) this way:

```
<?= empty($SubId3) ? 'homepage' : $SubId3; ?>
```

This is basically equivalent to this:

```
<?php
if (empty($SubId3)) {
    echo 'homepage';
}
else {
    echo $SubId3;
}
?>
```

So the `<?=` short-hand should only be used to pass one simple variable  or a ternary expression to it; everything else should use the common `<?php` tag.

---

Here's a test case for Alex (in the comments) because I can run the above code just fine with PHP 5.4.12, but he seems not to be able to.

**common.php**

```
<?= empty($SubId3) ? 'homepage' : $SubId3; ?>
```

**index.php** (visit this file then)

```
<?php
$SubId3 = 'test'; // <-- Comment this out for the "homepage" output
include 'common.php';
```

Comment: I changed it to this, but it only shows "homepage" as output.

Even when i set $SubId3 = 'test'; in the index.php

Comment: @Alex [Here](http://pastebin.com/f2ikz5Mw) (Pastebin, sorry) is the code I had tried. If you add ?s to the URL it should output "test" and otherwise "homepage". Using PHP 5.4.12, this works just fine for me.

Comment: @Alex You can't run PHP code in pastebin. `?s` is not necessary in the answer, it's just a means of testing, since it will depend on whether or not `$SubId3` is set or not, which the OP would do before through means of an included files or something. How familiar are you with PHP?

Comment: @Alex I _explicitly_ tested it by including another file that contains `$SubId3` or not instead of `?s` and it still works fine. What PHP version are you trying this on?

Comment: @Alex See the bottom part of my answer I've just added for you

Comment: @Luuk you too, can you try the "test case for Alex" please? I don't see why this would work only for me.

Comment: @Alex What was the problem before? // Also, yeah, I updated my test case after two minutes (or so) because I saw that his files were the other way around, so it fits the OP's scenario, too.

Answer (score 0):

i think this

```
<?=$SubId3; if (empty($SubId3)) { echo 'homepage'; } ?>
```

should be

```
<?php $SubId3; if (empty($SubId3)) { echo 'homepage'; } ?>



<?=?> is short for <?php echo?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This wont work:

```
<?=$SubId3; if (empty($SubId3)) { echo 'homepage'; } ?>
```

If you want to print some stuff, you have to use only the variable, in one block and the IF on another.

```
<?=$SubId3?>
```

And:

```
<?php if(empty($SubId3)) { echo 'homepage'; } ?>
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try
    `<?php 
    /* echo $SubId3; */
    if (empty($SubId3)) {
        echo 'homepage';
    } else {
        echo $SubId3;
    }
    ?>`

Consider using different style of coding.
In PHP you have generally three variants:

- PHP code only
- HTML files with just some echoes
- Intermixed PHP and HTML

In first you use `echo` to output every single bit of the HTML.

Second means you include a PHP script at the top of your HTML file and call appropriate functions / insert text into the template. Just so you can edit your HTML separately from your PHP.

Third makes for sometimes unreadable and complex code, but is fast to write.

```
<?php if($something) { 
        while($otherthing) { ?>
    <B>text=<?=$index ?></B>
<?php }} ?>
```

Just a food for thought.

Comment: Tried your Top example, but still i can only menage to get the output "homepage"

Comment: @Luuk If the first code in this post doesn't work, something is wrong with how you're setting the variable.

Comment: If you get "homepage" not the code itself, then you obviously have short tags enabled. Only other thing I can think of is weird characters in the _including_ file source. What editor are you using?

Comment: Check your file paths. Are you editing and saving where you're including from?

Comment: Simply usting dreamweaver

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer guys, thanks for all the help.

I needed to set it in the PrintHeader like this:

```
<?
include "../../common.php";
printHeader('BlogNr1', 'BlogNr2', 'BlogNr3');
?>
```

And the index had to look like this:

```
<?
include "../../common.php";
printHeader('BlogNr1', 'BlogNr2', 'BlogNr3');
?>
```

Somebody on skype helped me. thanks anyways guys!